# Why do I get a hard edge when mixing a Transparent and Glossy node with a Fresnel node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

When I use Fresnel node to mix Transparent node and Glossy node I get a hard edge between these nodes.

[image: Render]
[image: Nodes]

However then I see Fresnel node and see the gradient mask, there is no hard edge.

[image: Render]
[image: Nodes]

Why mix gives me a hard edge? The same problem I have with some other nodes.

I use Blender 2.82 and Blender 2.81. Render - Cycles.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the alpha blend mode, currently you are in Alpha Clip which rounds the alpha value to 0 for values < 0.5 and to 1 for values > 0.5.

Make sure your render engine is set to Eevee first :

[image]

Alpha Clip :

[image]

Alpha Blend :

[image]

If you want to tweak it further, add a Color ramp between the Fresnel and the mix shader, set to B spline interpolation, and move the white cursor way to the left :

[image]

Note you can get the same setup with a principled BSDF, which will be more physically correct :

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I use Cycles. Sorry, I forgot to say that. Can you help me with Cycles?

Answer (score 0):

The only work around I've found for this in Cycles is to use a RefractionBSDF instead of the TransparentBSDF. Set the value of the IOR's to be the same. Use a value node to control both and you shouldn't have that annoying hard line.